# Entity Framework error: The data reader is incompatible

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I wrote a query in Entity Framework, as:

```
var query1 = database.Database.SqlQuery<customer>("select name from customer where shomaremoshtare ='" + txt_shomaremoshtare.Text.Trim() + "'");
```

When I run this, I get this error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'moavaghatModel.customer'. A member of the type, 'id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning only the name of the entity in your select, try to return all the fields like this:

```
var query1 = database.Database.SqlQuery<customer>("select * from customer where shomaremoshtare ='" + txt_shomaremoshtare.Text.Trim() + "'");
```

Comment: i only want name in my select

Comment: So you should change .SqlQuery<customer> to .SqlQuery<string>